# How to Divide 1 value from input box to 10 another input box divided by 10 without rounding

Tags: javascript, jquery, divide, warehouse

I am making a form to input Products to warehouse, So, the condition that i want is:

> When I type and enter a value in **Quantity box** (Blue circle), I want that value shown to another 10 input boxes pallet list (red circle), **But** it has to be **69 Pcs** in each box ( **69 is only total that actually fit on the pallet in real warehouse** ) and if it still have rest, put the last rest in the **last box**. This is the illustration that might help :

[image]

Say, I have produce **630 PCS** items, and when I put **630** to the Quantity Box, It should be shown **69 PCS** in every pallet list, **69** until it cannot be divided again. The rest of the divide, have to be placed on the last box.

**Example :**

> Quantity : 630 PCS
>
> Pallet 1: 69
>
> Pallet 2: 69
>
> Pallet 3: 69
>
> Pallet 4: 69
>
> Pallet 5: 69
>
> Pallet 6: 69
>
> Pallet 7: 69
>
> Pallet 8: 69
>
> Pallet 9: 69
>
> Pallet 10: 9 (The rest have to be on the last pallet)

Can someone help me? Thank you, Terima Kasih.

Comment: Please add your code. Both HTML and JavaScript. If you have tried something, please post that too and tell what part is not working.

Comment: the code is just bunch of input boxes... nothing special sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the modulo operation and the integer division. The `%` operator in JavaScript works fine as modulo on positive numbers. You do not need correct modulo operations on negative numbers for this particular problem. The integer division is a floored normal division. The `Math` object provides a `floor` method.

```js
var
  byId     = document.getElementById.bind(document),
  intVal   = id => parseInt(byId(id).value),
  onChange = ev =>
  {
    let
      qty  = intVal('quantity'),
      ppb  = intVal('peaces-per-box'),
      rest = qty % ppb,
      html = ''
    ;
    if(!qty || !ppb)
      return byId('pallets').innerHTML = '';

    for (var c = Math.floor(qty / ppb), i = 0; i < c; i++)
      html += `<div></div><lable for="pallet-${i}"></lable> <input id="pallet-${i}" value="${ppb}"></div>\n`;
    if(rest)
      html += `<div></div><lable for="pallet-${i}"></lable> <input id="pallet-${i}" value="${rest}"><div></div>\n`;
    byId('pallets').innerHTML = html;
  }
;
byId('quantity'      ).addEventListener('change', onChange);
byId('peaces-per-box').addEventListener('change', onChange);
onChange();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Quantities</title>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <lable for="quantity">quantity</lable>
      <input id="quantity" type="number" min="0" step="1" placeholder="enter quantity">
    </div>
    <div>
      <lable for="peaces-per-box">peaces per box</lable>
      <input id="peaces-per-box" type="number" min="1" step="1" placeholder="enter max. peaces per box">
      <div id="pallets">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: what should i do if i wont add the new box sir?i mean box should be there in first place

Comment: You could set the values of existing boxes for example. Just be creative. It's up to you how you design your UI.

Comment: thanks sir, i have found another trick to make the inbox <= 10. So much appreciate thanks.

Comment: You should read more about DOM manipulation if you want to preserve contents of the generated input boxes. But this is not part of the question. You can use `Math.max(10, Math.floor(qty / ppb))` to get the count of full boxes but not more than 10. Then you need an additional condition to prevent a new box for the rest peaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = 630
let arr = []
for(let i=0;i<9;i++){
    arr.push(0)
    if(input>=69){
        arr.push(69)
        input-=69
    }
}
arr.push(input)
```

I don't know if this is what you want.